# How do you expand an pure ACL2 script into a fully-fledged program

Tags: lisp, proof, reliability, formal-methods, acl2

I see a lot of [resources](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/moore/acl2/) about how to use ACL2 to prove code, as you would expect, but none on how to use your proved code in production.

Do I tweak my ACL2 code to work with CLISP/Scheme/Clojure? Can ACL2 run my code too?
(where are the tutorials, am I using ACL2 not in according to its purpose?)

Thanks!

Comment: This is indeed an _interesting_ question, but it's probably not a good fit for StackOverflow, as it's too broad at best, and primarily opinion based at worst. "There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs." "Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise."

Comment: That said, this _is_ an interesting question, and there might be other sites on the stack exchange network where it might be more on topic.  Perhaps you might be able to rework it and ask on http://programmers.stackexchange.com (you'll need to check what's "on-topic" there, though).

Comment: perhaps I should have said "How do I use ACL2 to write an executable/interpretable program."

Comment: You can use ACL2 in production the same way you'd use any other interpreter.  To do this, I would (1) include all of the books necessary to run your scripts, then I'd (2) call `save-exec` (see its documentation topic), finally, I'd use shell primitives like `>` and `|` to pipe input to that ACL2 image.